# Problem with WCF Service - The protocol 'http' is not supported. How to resolve?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, iis, windows-vista

I'm after setting up a WCF service on my dev box but I'm getting an error when accessing it. I've set the [service up as per this guide](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-4-Host_a_WCF_Service_in_IIS_7_-and-amp%3B_Windows_2008_-_The_right_way.aspx). It's is written in **VS2008 / C# / .NET 3.5** and my dev box is **Vista SP2** with **IIS 7**. At the moment the service is nothing more than the default structure since I am literally after testing a connection to it.

I've checked what needs to be installed and I'm fairly sure I've got everything enabled, screen shot below shows current options:

[image: Windows IIS Options]

Full error message on accessing **http://localhost:8000/Service.svc** is as follows:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The protocol 'http' is not supported. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The protocol 'http' is not supported.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: The protocol 'http' is not supported.]
   System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +11536522
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +194
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.ExecuteSynchronous(HttpApplication context, Boolean flowContext) +176
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule.ProcessRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +278
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +68
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4016; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4016
```

Any suggestions on how to go about debugging / fixing the error would be gratefully received. Googling the error gives very little help. I've probably missed something really obvious!

**Edit** - web.config as requested (apologies for its length):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                    <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
                    <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                </sectionGroup>
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings/>
    <system.web>
        <!--
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
        -->
        <compilation debug="true">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
        <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->
        <pages>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <httpHandlers>
            <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
            </compiler>
            <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
            </compiler>
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
    <system.web.extensions>
        <scripting>
            <webServices>
                <!--
              Uncomment this section to enable the authentication service. Include 
              requireSSL="true" if appropriate. 

          <authenticationService enabled="true" requireSSL = "true|false"/>
          -->
                <!--
              Uncomment these lines to enable the profile service, and to choose the 
              profile properties that can be retrieved and modified in ASP.NET AJAX 
              applications.

           <profileService enabled="true"
                           readAccessProperties="propertyname1,propertyname2"
                           writeAccessProperties="propertyname1,propertyname2" />
          -->
                <!--
              Uncomment this section to enable the role service.

          <roleService enabled="true"/>
          -->
            </webServices>
            <!--
        <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="true" enableCaching="true" />
        -->
        </scripting>
    </system.web.extensions>
    <!--
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="Service" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
                <!-- Service Endpoints -->
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IService">
                    <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost"/>
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**Edit 2** - I've removed the paragraph about creating a Delphi Win32 client since Delphi 2007 doesn't support SOAP 1.2, which is what the WCF Service uses. Delphi 2007 only supports SOAP 1.0... So client will now be a C# WinForms app.

Comment: You've installed the service host as port 8000?

Comment: Yes (following the guide I linked). I've tried port 80 as well. No joy.

Comment: Please post the web.config, I suspect it's a config issue.

Comment: Try this: In iis configuration manager you need to right click on the service you invoked choose "manage web site" then go to advance setting.
Add http in enabled protocols.

Comment: You sir are a genius, pop that in an answer so I can give you the rep points. I'm not well up on IIS 7.0 so I'd have never found that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer for me was the following (provided by Lazarus in the comments, but hasn't come back to post as an answer):

1. Fired up **Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager**.
2. Opened up the **Sites folder** and **selected the Site in question**.
3. **Right clicked** it, then selected **Manage Web Site** and then **Advanced Settings...**
4. On the resulting popup, I entered **http** in the **Enabled Protocols** row.
5. Closed the popup and restarted the Site, and that was it. Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

I found that it is almost always a problem with the way the `endpoint`, `bindings`, and/or the `behavior` is configured.

For the most part, if your web site in IIS does not have an HTTP binding, then make sure to explicitly set the httpGet httpGetEnabled='false' in the `configuration/system.serviceModel/behaviors/serviceBehaviors/behavior/serviceMetadata` configuration respective to your WCF service.  The path above ofcourse is refering to your web or app.config file.

In addition, if you have an endpoint that has 'http://' in the address, remove it.  WCF pays attention to these things and will throw the same *ambiguous* error message.  There is a whole *maze* of mis-configurations that produce the same error messages.  (I hate that about WCF.)  I which it was more specific like: "Hey dumm as#!  You have an HTTP in one of your endpoint addresses but IIS has no HTTP binding!"  ;P  Atleast this way I won't be chasing my tail.

Likewise, I never use the `mex` endpoints as they are more trouble then they are worth.  Instead, use the `httpsHelpPageUrl` and `httpsHelpPageEnabled` attributes in the `configuration/system.serviceModel/behaviors/serviceBehaviors/behavior/serviceDebug` config element (assuming you're using `HTTPS`).

Answer (score 1):

Answer for me was to disable and then enable again **Metadata Over HTTP**.

1. Fired up **Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager**.
2. Opened up the **Sites folder** and **selected the Site in question**.
3. **Right clicked** it, then selected **Manage WCF and WF Services** and then **Configure...**
4. On the **General** tab, I unchecked **Enable metadata over HTTP** (yes, it was checked already).
5. Clicked on **Apply** (and confirmed the recycle application warning).
6. Checked **Enable metadata over HTTP**.
7. Clicked on **Apply** (and confirmed the recycle application warning), and that was it. Fixed!

...Or maybe an AppPool recycle would be enough.